# Fix the regular expression used in the rearrange_name function so that it can match middle names, middle initials, as well as double surnames

Tags: python

Can anyone try to figure out how to fix this code:

```
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^(\w*), (\w*)$", name)
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

it‘s supposed to output "John F., Kennedy"

Comment: It's not matching `F.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know how!

```
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^([\w \.-]*), ([\w \.-]*)$", name)
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

Answer (score 3):

As [MYousefi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991397/myousefi) pointed out, your regular expression isn't compatible with middle names. I found out the following using [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

- `\w` matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

The string "John F." contains two characters what aren't word characters:

- Space ( )
- Dot (`.`)

Fixing your original regex would look like this (I would recommend `+` instead of `*`):

```
^(\w+), ([\w. ]+)$
```

To handle "double surnames", you have to allow spaces and hyphens in the first group:

```
^([\w -]+), ([\w. ]+)$
```

#### Alternate solution

It might be easier to solve your problem using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead of using regex:

```
def rearrange_name(name):
    tokens = name.split(", ")
    return " ".join(reversed(tokens))

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

This codes splits the name, re-arranges the two halves and joins them back together.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and it worked.

```
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^(\w*), (.*)$", name)
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^(\w*), (\w*.*)$", name)
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^(\w*), ([a-zA-Z]*.*)$", name)
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Kennedy, John F.")
print(name)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).